# $this->db->insert_id(); For insert Id works fine. But I want to insert business name also how

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

```
$suppliers_acc['supplier_sign_up_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
```

This is work for me.

But I want to add business name.

```
$suppliers_acc['business_name'] = $this->db->insert_business_name();
```

So, how to do please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like that

```
$suppliers_acc['business_name'] = $this->db->insert_business_name();
```

And implement this method in your db class if needed.

Comment: thankyou it's work form me -- solution $suppliers_acc['business_name'] = $supplier_sign_up['business_name'];